# Add Custom Field to Payment, Deposit, & Refund (NetSuite)

Tags: netsuite, custom-fields

Have a field created which was added to both `Payments` and `Deposits` in NetSuite and would like to have this also show up on `Refunds`. Not seeing the option to apply this to those. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the Refund form and choose to show your custom field on the form. If you did not specify a subtab when you created the custom field, it will be under Screen Fields > Custom when you customize the form.

Comment: Thanks, it was because we had Standard Form only for Customer Refunds. This was simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

Go to that created Transaction Body Field, and click on Apply To Forms button, check the Refund form checkbox.